# Getting Resource configuration is not modifiable in this context when deploying RESTful Jersey service in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, intellij-idea, jersey

I am writing a RESTful API using Jersey/Tomcat and I've been encountering:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [com.tuiasi.petru.sop.service.MyApplication] threw exception
.......
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
```

when calling the API.

I believe I have exhausted many trivial solutions, including ones that I saw here. I suppose that there is something to do with the deployment configuration I have set up in IntelliJ IDEA, which I am using. So basically my code is as follows:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

public MyApplication() {
        register(...);
    }
}

@Path("data")
public class DataController {
...

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response list() {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SOPStorageService server</display-name>
</web-app>
```

When I deploy in IntelliJ IDEA, I choose a war exploded kind of artifact where I add the storage service with all its dependencies.

The only issue I still haven't ruled out completely is a possible incompatibility between some jars. I am wondering yet if someone has a better eye at spotting a possible issue in this particular case.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem and I'm also leaning into incompatibility between some dependencies. It works on localhost but not on Azure App Service (it actually used to work but doesn't anymore)

Answer (score -1):

@ApplicationPath("api") -> @ApplicationPath("/api")
@Path("data") -> @Path("/data")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).